# How to set single layout for all Android devices and tablets?

Tags: android

I am android beginner. I want to set a single android layout which should be applicable for all android devices and tablets. Is there any chance to do this thing? Please help me.

Comment: That's a fairly general question but the standard layouts for android allow you to create one single layout for both phones and tablets. Maybe you should explain what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried so far

Comment: Yes you can definitely do this. Learn for using the android:layout_weight property. you will get your answer

Comment: That's the default. No work required

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use TableLayout by creating Rows and columns it behave same in all android devices. try this link for table layout it will help you

http://android.programmerguru.com/android-tablelayout-example/